# PHP MySQL inner join multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I got this tables:

Table **user**:

```
|    userid    | nickname   |   profilpic  |
|33460794335580| KING_ED    |5435345345.jpg|
|86426315360152| Caro010716 |654664656.jpg |
```

Table **nachrichten**:

```
|              file             |      user1      |     user2     |
|33460794335580_86426315360152  | 33460794335580  |86426315360152 |
```

I use this code to get nickname and profilpic from user1:

```
$myid = 33460794335580;
$msgquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT
            user.nickname,user.profilpic,nachrichten.user1,nachrichten.user2
            FROM user
            INNER JOIN nachrichten ON nachrichten.user1 = user.userid
            WHERE nachrichten.file LIKE '%$myid%'");


while($daten = mysqli_fetch_assoc($msgquery))
{
    echo 'The user-id ' . $daten['user1'] . ' got the Nickname: ' . $daten['nickname'] . ' and profilpic is: ' . $daten['profilpic'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'The user-id ' . $daten['user2'] . ' got the Nickname: ' . ???????????????? . ' and profilpic is: ' . ?????????????? . '<br/>';
}
```

But how can I get also the nickname and profilpic from user2?

Comment: Can I ask why you build the table **nachrichten** like that?

Comment: Its for private chat system. This way I can always check if the chat file allready exist and so on

Comment: You'd be better off building a link table so you'd have file & a new file_id field on the nachrichten table (removing the userX fields) and then create a new file_user link table with user_id & file_id as fields. That would solve a problem of if you ever need to increase the number of user columns on nachrichten. You would simply add a new row to the new file_user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another join with user table for second user

```
SELECT 
  u.nickname nickname1,
  u.profilpic profilpic1,
  u1.nickname nickname2,
  u1.profilpic profilpic2,
  n.user1,
  n.user2 
FROM
  nachrichten n
  INNER JOIN  user u 
    ON n.user1 = u.userid 
  INNER JOIN  user u1 
    ON n.user2 = u1.userid 
 WHERE ....
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe016/3)

Comment: This is realy hard to understand, do I need to leave u. like it is or should it be user. and so on?

Comment: @user2966167 In your current query you have joined user with `user1` from table `nachrichten` so it will give you the details for only user who matches with `user1` in order to get the information for `user2` you need another join as `u1` to your user table to fetch the information for `user2` from `nachrichten` table hope it makes sense

Comment: Ok now I figured it out xD I kept WHERE nachrichten.file instead n.file.. works now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u1.nickname AS user1_name,u1.profilpic AS user1_pic, u2.nickname AS user2_name, u2.profilpic AS user2_pic 
FROM nachrichten n
INNER JOIN user u1 ON n.user1 = u1.userid
INNER JOIN user u2 ON n.user2 = u2.userid
WHERE nachrichten.file LIKE '%$myid%'
```